# Vuejs can vue file be regarded as json compliant object definition

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have just started vuejs and noticed that some kind of strucutre in `.vue` files.

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            temp: {},
            list: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addNew: function() {
        },        
        entitySaved($event) {
        }
    }
}
```

Can we suppose `export` to be `json` compliant structure? If so, what is meant by `data()` function without it property name? Losts of such styles can also be seen in `vuex`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a json its just an object with functions,objects
you can make one by your self to check it like:

```
export default {
    hey(){
       return true
    }
}
```

just import something like that and check it results